# Creating a development environment for large production database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

There is a Windows 2008 Server running SQL Server meant as a big data solution. The (production) database is about 1TB. Right now, all the testing and development is against this production server.

Copying the database or backing up the database, I was told, is out of the question for a development database since there isn't an extra server to use. The size of the database seems to be another limitation since it is large. Not only that, this database will undoubtedly grow larger (5TB) rather soon.

How are some ways to setup a development environment for testing and developing against a database in such situations?

Comment: If you want your company to remain in business, stop testing and developing against production IMMEDIATELY. It's not a question of "if", it's just a matter of "when" something will go horribly wrong and you lose valuable data. You need a development environment, period. The dev DB doesn't have to have all of the data from production, as long as it has the same schema and a reasonable sample set to work against.

Comment: Ideally, your development environment mimics production as much as possible. If this is not possible due to hardware constraints, you have 2 choices: (1) develop against production, or (2) trim a development database down until it meets hardware limitations. (1) is so evil it begs for solution (2), which would mean that performance testing will have to be carefully tested on the live servers. For non-altering queries, this can be fine, for queries that alter data... you'll have to chance it that the logic errors are filtered out in dev, and only performance can now be a problem.

Comment: // I was told, is out of the question for a development database since there isn't an extra server to use.//   That is insane.  Look for a new job if the company is so fiscally "on the bubble" it cannot buy one server for development, non-production use.

Comment: I'm always intrigued by companies willing to invest whats required to support a 5TB database, yet can't come up with a dev/testing server.  Put together a risk assessment document that includes the cost in 'time lost' to the company from a developer accidentally locking a major production table for 15 minutes and see if they are willing to get a dev server to off-set that risk.  If that doesn't work, show what the cost of a table accidentally being dropped by a developer is instead.

Comment: Sounds to me like you asked for the wrong thing.  You don't need an exact copy of the production database.  You need the schema and a limited, but realistic, data set.  I would fire anyone that allowed a regular dev near a live production DB server.  Those should be locked down to an extremely limited set of people for change management.  People that knew the price of failure.

Comment: Calculate the costs of a separate server (including a development license of SQL-Server which is about 70-100$ + 100$ for Win7). You can use an ordinary PC, even from the leftovers of your office. It is not a bad idea to develop using a slow server as it makes you otimize for speed as well. The dev-PC will cost less than 1000$. Calculate the cost for a production outage for 5 minutes due to some lost/corrupt data. Show the results to your bosses. The only argument that really counts is: money.

Comment: This is going to cost. The first **"Ooooops"** moment will be an expensive one. And probably the **last** "Oooops" moment. And even more probably the _last moment of the company itself_...

Comment: You most definitely need another database that you can use for testing. As others have already pointed out this is a disaster waiting to happen.

The simplest thing you can do is to create scripts for existing database and then send these to devs so they can create their own local version of database w/o data.

If you need some data from database in testing environment take some time to do analysis and see what is the minimum that you need. If your devs say they need all data to do the testing they are probably lazy ;).

You can try some third party schema and data comparison tools...

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the feedback. These are great warnings and insights. We will be changing the approach and we're currently looking at setting up a Dev box or working locally (probably locally). I can't thank you all enough for taking a moment to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Create a new database within the same SQL Server instance.
2. Create a new SQL Server instance running on the same physical machine.

I recommend the latter since there is less risk of crossover and the logins and users will be all separate, meaning you can secure your production environment from accidental access.

For more information on instances you can look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174516%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

To populate your new instance you can set up an extract from your production environment that only takes a portion of the data.  That way you won't have to have double the disk space.  You should be able to use Sql Server Integration Services.  Get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx).

P.S. You really ought to get a completely separate development environment, but it sounds like they don't let you in on the big decisions.

Comment: If they are going to do this, they may as well let the dev's install SQL Developer on their local boxes and have a very trimmed down version of the data.

Comment: While I recognize the foul smell of my answer, and can empathize with the emotional need to hit the downvote button, I must point out I am the only one who actually answered the QUESTION, given the constraints as stated-- everyone else is just telling the poor guy to tell his boss to do something that he isn't going to do.  <3

Comment: Good explanation, vote changed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and insights from both of you!

Comment: @JohnWu Friend, its a late visit on this topic. But your answer is very useful. But can you please explain one point in your answer which I didnt understand. the point where you mentioned about For avoiding double disk space, its good to use SSIS. Can you please explain that a little for this context if we have a clone of production DB in another instance on the same server